# Defining lists for multiple indices in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, lists, pgfplotstable, foreach

I am trying to plot several column pairs using the `\foreach` loop command with `pgfplotstable` in the following way.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \x {data.txt}
\begin{axis}
    [
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},     
    ]
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/1,2/3,4/5,6/7,8/9,10/11}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[smooth,color=blue,no marks] table[x index=\i,y index=\j] {\x};
    }
    \temp
    } 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automate list creation over two variables as in something like

```
 \foreach \i/\j in {0/1,2/3,...,10/11}
```

which does not seem to work?

Comment: You can pull table elements using \pgfplotstablegetelem and construct a list/macro using \xdef

Comment: ... and there is of course `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, see the end of section 4.6.3 of the manual...

Comment: If your values are consecutive then you can go about it as `\foreach\x[count=\xi from 0] in{1,...,11}` or use `evaluate` if you have complicated expression\

Comment: Duplicate, I suppose? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37601/possible-to-combine-and-x-y-in-tikzs-foreach

Comment: Unfortunately, `evaluate` returns a number that is a floating point number and cannot be passed as a row/column index for plotting purposes.

Comment: `int(<calculation>)` gives you an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and the earlier asked question, I figured out a way to define successive lists based on a parent list definition, that can be passed as indices for plotting with `pgfplotstable`. The working code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \x {data.txt}
\begin{axis}
   [
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},     
   ]
   \foreach[evaluate=\j using int(\i+1)] \i in {0,2,...,38}
   {
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[smooth,color=blue,no marks] table[x index=\i,y index=\j] {\x};
   }
   \temp
   } 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```